# Problem with making UILabel following UISlider Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video, video-player

I am making a custom player, and I am using UISlider to display current progress of video(Movie/Tv Show), but I want my label to display current time and to follow UISlider thumb. Currently its following UIThumb but for a milisecond it goes to original position then goes to UIThumb position here is the code:

```
 let labelUpdateInterval = CMTime(seconds: 0.000000001, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    sliderObserver = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: labelUpdateInterval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { elapsedTime in
        self.followSlider()
    })
```

This is in viewWillAppear, I am adding observer.

```
 func followSlider() {
    let trackRect = progressBar.trackRect(forBounds: progressBar.frame)
    let thumbRect = progressBar.thumbRect(forBounds: progressBar.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: progressBar.value)
    trenutnoVrijemeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: self.trenutnoVrijemeLabel.center.y)
}
```

This is the method.
Did someone else have same issue? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I do not see where you add the observer. Usually, it would be better to add in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Observer is added in viewDidAppear i wrote it, that is not the problem here, the observer works, its just that in some moments label goes back to original position that goes back to thumb position. Is there a different way to pull this off?

Comment: No problem, but without more code it is difficult to track what you did wrong. Good luck so.